# How To Exit app by double tap on back button in NativeScript Apps

Tags: nativescript

Exit app on double tap on back button in Nativescript

Please help me with snippet of code

Comment: Does `Exit` mean dismissing app or killing it totally?

Comment: Dismissing only :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that I have found:

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var application = require("application")

var activity = application.android.startActivity ||
        application.android.foregroundActivity ||
        frameModule.topmost().android.currentActivity ||
        frameModule.topmost().android.activity;
var lastPress;

activity.onBackPressed = function() {
    var timeDelay = 500
    if (lastPress + timeDelay > java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        var startMain = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(android.content.Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        activity.startActivity(startMain);

        // If you want to kill the app totally, use these codes instead of above
        // activity.finish();
        // java.lang.System.exit(0);

    } else {
        frameModule.topmost().goBack();
    }
    lastPress = java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where shud i include this ?

Comment: this can be put anywhere

Comment: how to use the java.lang.system exit(0) with any import to java. moreover i'm using {N} with angular.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Just one thing, how can I add a toast on first back press to say "Press back again to exit"?

Comment: @VeeK inside else block

Answer (score 0):

for Angular

```
import * as application from 'tns-core-modules/application';

exitapp=0
ngOnInit() {
application.android.on(application.AndroidApplication.activityBackPressedEvent, this.handleBackButton, this);
}

handleBackButton(args: any) {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            args.cancel = true;
            if (this.routerExtensions.canGoBack()) {
                this.routerExtensions.back();
            }else{
                
                this.exitapp++
                this.getData.toast('Press again to exit')
                if(this.exitapp==2){
                    application.android.foregroundActivity.finish();
                }
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    this.exitapp=0
                },2000)
            }
        })
    }
```